# How to efficiently populate a matrix given a very large table using python?

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I have a table of three columns 'customer', 'item_id', 'ct_id', but the rows are about 3 million.   The unique 'item_id' has 20350 entries, and the 'customer' has 
2485 entries.  Each customer may buy any number of items among the 20350 kinds of items

The goal is to build a recommend system based on the table.  First I want to construct a matrix of 2485x20350,  whose row is 'custmer' and column is 'item_id'.
Each element is the occurrence count of the 'customer' & 'item_id' pair in the table.  THen I can build similarity matrix based on this customer/item matrix.

I tried to use pivot_table in pandas, like this:
d_pivt = dt.pivot_table(index=['cstm_num','it_num'], aggfunc='count'),

I just wondering, with this information, what is the most efficient way to build the matrix I wanted.

Thanks,

Comment: So you tried using `pivot_table`, what went wrong in your attempt? Did it throw an error, was it just too slow? Please elaborate on why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you said `'item_id'` in the columns and `'customer'` in the rows.

```
d_pivt = dt.pivot_table(values='ct_id', index='customer',
                        columns='item_id', aggfunc='count')
```

---

***demonstration***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 3)),
                  columns=['customer', 'item_id', 'ct_id'])

df.pivot_table('ct_id', 'customer', 'item_id', 'count')
```

[image]

Comment: I want to create a matrix with customer as row, and item_id as column.

Comment: @Y.Liu I've updated my post.  If this isn't what you want, then you need to show us what you want because telling us isn't working.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tested on my data. This is exactly what I wanted. Now my customer/item matrix looks like this after I remove the NaN:

Answer (score 0):

@piRSquared  Your method works just as I wanted.  Now my customer/item matrix looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD1Ax.jpg)

I was not allowed to add pictures yet. :-(

But i got the matrix I want, whose dimension is 2485x20350. 
 You can see by the image link above, there are lots of zeros because a custmer may only buy several hundreds of the total items. 
I tried to compute the item correlation matrix using:

```
sall_pvtb = sales_all.pivot_table(values='cm_id', index='cstm_num',  
columns = 'it_num', aggfunc='count')

sall_pvtb.fillna(0, inplace = True)

sall_corr = sall_pvtb.corr()
```

But the item correlation computation takes really long time because it is a 20350x20350 size matrix. Correlation computation done sparsely?